# OAuth2 third party authentication with own tokens / no session

Tags: node.js, authentication, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, passport.js

I'd like to be able to sign into my node app using LinkedIn, an email and password, Facebook, and possibly others. I don't want to use sessions/cookies. Instead, I want to use a header with a token for authorization -- jwt or something else. I'm open to anything here.

My question is the same as the one asked here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/passportjs/DJZZGKXDLsk -- I want the users to go through the following steps:

1. User comes to my site
2. User logs in through LinkedIn
3. User is redirected to post-login on my site
4. User can continue to interact with my site using header tokens (not session cookies)

[Passport for LinkedIn OAuth2](https://github.com/auth0/passport-linkedin-oauth2) more or less works for what I need it for, but the only problem is that it looks like this is entirely geared towards using sessions with cookies. After the callback url is hit on my server, I don't see a way to get tokens back to the client securely.

It also seems like I can use the [LinkedIn frontend JS SDK](https://www.google.com/url?q=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.linkedin.com%2Fdocs%2Fgetting-started-js-sdk&sa=D&sntz=1&usg=AFQjCNH3-9fUt_BgHgk4Vf3loNwdu1jvxw) to have users authenticate and post-authentication they can make a POST request to my server and at that point I would be able to confirm authentication with LinkedIn and respond with the tokens I create for authentication in the POST body. I'm not sure if this is recommended or secure and I don't love the idea of having the LinkedIn API key in the frontend JavaScript either.

How can I use LinkedIn OAuth2 to authenticate to my site and keep the authentication without cookies/sessions?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why don't you want use sessions with cookies?

Comment: @Quy Token authentication seems to be a more modern, preferred solution. Sticky sessions are not required at a minimum.